# Как узнать оригинальный размер изображения?

Tags: javascript

Как можно узнать оригинальный размер изображения, а не тот что указан в width и height?

Comment: видимо Вас интересует  [naturalHeight()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_img_naturalheight.asp)

Comment: А ширина naturalWidth соответственно?

Comment: так точно. [naturalWidth()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_img_naturalwidth.asp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У тега IMG есть атрибуты:

```
naturalHeight
naturalWidth
```

Каждый из них отвечает соответственно за оригинальную ширину / высоту